# how to delet specific character from a list in the loop in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-regex

this is the part of my code to retrive data from canadian stat data according to the chanpter and save them in the excel form then open these excel form and change them and save it in the text form.

the problem for me is that in the first column I want to eleminate - from it. I tried alot but it does'nt work at all.

```
    # Commodity: Specific Chapter
ch_numbers = ["02","04","10","11","12","15","20","23","38"]
startrow = 0
for ch_number in ch_numbers:
    dropdown_rC = driver.find_element_by_id('report_chapters')
    dd_rC = Select(dropdown_rC)
    dd_rC.select_by_value(ch_number) 

    #  for retriving the data and store it in the excel form
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/p[2]/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    Canada_Result=[]
    pages = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title]'))
    pages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick and @class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title][%d]' % (pages)).text.strip("Page\n")

    if pages == '':
        pages = 1
    
    for J in range (int(pages)):
        year_month = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[1]') # the year details in each row   //*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
        commodities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[2]/a')
        Countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[4]')
        quantities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[7]')
        weights = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[8]/abbr')
      
        time.sleep(1)

        period_entries = len(commodities)
        for i in range(period_entries):
            temporary_data= {'year':year_month[i].text,'Commodity':commodities[i].text,'Country':Countries[i].text,'quantity':quantities[i].text,'weight': weights[i].text }
            Canada_Result.append(temporary_data)
        
        df_data = pd.DataFrame(Canada_Result)

        df_data.to_excel('Canada_scrapping_result_'+ str(ch_number) +'.xlsx', index=False, header=0)

        if J == int(pages) - 1:
            print("Done")
            break
        # click on the Next button
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
        time.sleep(1)

    # ----------for convert the data in excel and save it again---------------
    df = pd.read_excel('Canada_scrapping_result_'+ str(ch_number) +'.xlsx') 

    
    



    df.to_csv('Remove_characters_'+str(ch_number)+'.txt', index=False, header=0)


    time.sleep(2)
    # Click Submit
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/p[2]/button').click() # For going to the next page
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Is this a list or a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @ it is from the panda dataframe. I get this list from webscrapping "selenium" and put it in the excel file and want to edited and save it again. this part is the edited part in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pandas `.str.replace()` method.

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.replace('-', '')
```

Comment: as you said I changed to :             df['year_month'] = df['year_month'].str.replace('-','')
unfortunately I get this error:  Exception has occurred: KeyError
'year_month'

Comment: Then that's not the correct name of the column.

Comment: @dear Barmar I tried a lot to do it but unfortunateley it doesn't work. Could you help me?

Comment: Edit the question and show a sample of your dataframe. `print(df.head())`

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: @SaeidVaygani at the `temporary_data=` part of your code, you are renaming the `year_month` column to `year`. Have you tried `df['year'] = df['year'].str.replace('-','')`

Answer (score 0):

If they are string values, you can use `replace` in  list comprehension for each row:

```py
#### Mock dataset
data = [["2022-01-01" , "0207.14.93.00" , "United States" , 2000 , "KGM"], 
        ["2022-01-01" , "0407.14.03.00" , "United States" , 3400, "KGM"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", "Num1", "Country", "Num1", "Col"])
#############

df.Date = [x.replace("-", "") for x in df.Date]
df
```

Output:

```
        Date    Num1            Country         Num1    Col
0   20220101    0207.14.93.00   United States   2000    KGM
1   20220101    0407.14.03.00   United States   3400    KGM
```

If they are loaded in as Timestamps, then try this:

```py
df.Date = df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: I tried a lot to solve it but it doesn't work with these codes!